# linux + how to calculate float numbers with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, bc

how to calculate float numbers: with bash

example

```
     DRIVER_MEMORY=$(( 5 * 0.6 * 0.9 ))
-bash: 5 * 0.6 * 0.9 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".6 * 0.9 ")
```

remark - results must be integer number  - so we can round the number to down

Comment: What is it you want though: `bash`, `awk`, or `bc`?

Comment: no matter but the best elegant approach

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: `bash` doesn't do float.  The syntax error really means "error: input not an integer".  `DRIVER_MEMORY=$((5*6*9/100))` or `DRIVER_MEMORY=$(((5*6*9+50)/100))` does _this_ calculation (depending on your desired rounding mode) if you want to avoid forking out another process

Comment: Write your own function for multiplication. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24431665/3776858) is an example of an integer division with floating point results.

Answer (score 0):

Awk solution:

```
 DRIVER_MEMORY=$( awk '{ print 5*0.6*0.9 }' <<< "")
```

bc solution:

```
DRIVER MEMORY=$(echo "5*0.6*0.9" | bc)
```

Comment: You could use a `BEGIN` statement instead of the null string redirect:  `DRIVER_MEMORY=$(awk 'BEGIN{print 5*0.6*0.9}')`